# Software Package homeowners assocation

Tags: accounting

Are there any recommendations for software packages to manage a 31 Unit Homeowners association with at least the following forcasting, budgetting, complaints, and banking integration.

Ideally cloud based, looking at < $100/month

Comment: Windows? Linux? MaC? Browser based? Android? iOs? Are you willing to pay? If so, what’s your budget? If not, please add the [tag:gratis] tag. Personally, I disagree that this is too broad, but the more detail that you can give us the better we can help you, so please do edit your question to give more detail and I am sure that you will get an answer.